# Closure seems not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor

I have this:

```
private isLogged(): boolean {
    //check cookie here
    let logged: boolean;
    browser.manage().getCookies().then((cookies: IWebDriverOptionsCookie[]) => {
       if (cookies.length == 0) {
        console.log('Is Not Logged');
        console.log('My cookies', cookies);
        logged = false;
    });
    console.log('isLogged: ' , logged);
    return logged;
}
```

When I run this, the logged is:

```
   undefined
```

I go into the Is Not Logged and My cookies inside.

Am I missing sth or just tired and do not see simple mistake ?

Comment: Your `logged` variable is assigned to asynchronously. It is logged before the promise has resolved.

Comment: What would be best to fix?

Comment: Not 100% agree this is a direct duplicate. May be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633969/value-of-a-function-in-javascriptprotractor-returns-as-undefined) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38262804/protractor-getting-undefined-while-trying-to-return-a-value) or there multiple similar threads is/are a better fit. Do they all need to be closed, or is this a special topic?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `isLogged()` function and return from it - the `browser.manage().getCookies()` promise has not yet been resolved - hence, the value of `logged` was never set.

Instead, let `isLogged` return a promise:

```
private isLogged(): boolean {
    return browser.manage().getCookies().then(function (cookies) {
      if (cookies.length == 0) {
        console.log('Is Not Logged');
        return false
      } else {
        console.log('Is Logged');
        console.log('My cookies', cookies);
        return true
      }
    });
}
```

And, resolve once the value is needed:

```
isLogged().then(function (isLogged) {
    console.log(isLogged);
});
```

---

To gain more understanding in promises in Protractor, please see [Promises and the Control Flow](http://www.protractortest.org/#/control-flow#promises-and-the-control-flow) documentation page.